# Is it possible to reload a single Javascript file using Chrome Developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-developers-console

In many cases, I make some small changes to a JavaScript file, to see the result I have to reload the whole page.

Changes made in chrome's developer tool in "**Source**" tab do not save in file system.

So, is it possible to reload single JavaScript file alone?

Comment: Can you describe "small changes"? Are you changing `DOM` elements; `javascript` variables? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Not changing DOM elements. Small changes in logics, calculations and iterations.

Comment: What is expected result?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of much efficient way to do this but one way you can do this is by adding a breakpoint at the start of the JavaScript file or at the block you want to add or delete changes to.

Then when you reload, the debugger will pause on that breakpoint, and you can make any changes you want to the source, save the file and then run the debugger through the modified code.

But here's a thing that you should know:  next reload the changes will vanish but at least it let's you run some slightly modified JavaScript client side codes.

Comment: I was able to just edit the script in the Sources tab and save! Had a session timeout issue that involved the computer going to sleep and waking back up so this solution works well once the issue finally does occur.